# Given a data set of $n$ distinct values, show that the number of distinct bootstrap samples is $(2n-1)$ choose $n$.

Tags: statistics, bootstrap-sampling

Given a data set of $n$ distinct values, what is the proof that the number of distinct bootstrap samples is $(2n-1)$ choose $n$?

Comment: You need to say which of several possible bootstrap procedures you are using: _Nonparametric_ or _parametric_? _One_ sample or _two_? What parameter(s) is (are) being estimated? One reason I ask for particulars is that bootstraps I have done have involved sampling _with_ replacement, and ${2n-1 \choose n}$ brings to mind sampling _without_ replacement.

Comment: Bootstrap can be used for parametric or nonparametric and the resampling or bootstrap samples are always done with replacement. Example:data set is {1,2,3} . That is n=3 .Bootstrap samples of size 3 are {1,1,1}, {2,2,2},{3,3,3},{1,2,3}, {2,1,1} ,{3,2,2} ,{3,1,1} ,{2,3,3} ,{1,3,3} ,{1,2,2} . Since n=3, (2n-1) choose n is 10 which I've enumerated. Thanks.